# JPA - is Cascade and Orphan Removal redundant

Tags: java, jpa, orm

In a JPA entity, is it redundant to have:

```
cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true
```

From my understanding `orphanRemoval` is basically a more aggressive version of `cascade`, so would there ever be a case when `cascade` would catch something that `orphanRemoval` wouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`orphanRemoval` would only cover the `CascadeType.REMOVE`.

If you remove the `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` and leave only the `orphanRemoval = true`, then you would miss out on the following operations which would not be cascaded anymore:

`{PERSIST, MERGE, REFRESH, DETACH}.`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! I totally didn't even consider it in terms of persisting. I was only thinking about the removing. This clears it up for me!